# Do photons, virtual photons, conduct straight through static magnetic fields?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In the double slit experiment.

If the double slits are made from a paramagnetic material does that change the interference pattern?

For example all objects emit (give out) and absorb (take in) thermal radiation, which is also called infrared radiation. Infrared radiation is a type of electromagnetic radiation, which involves waves rather than particles.

Paramagnetism is a form of magnetism whereby certain materials are weakly attracted by an externally applied magnetic field, and form internal, induced magnetic fields in the direction of the applied magnetic field.

Does the material, the magnetic field(s) between the slit change the interference pattern

If we had a plastic slit compared to an iron slit?

Thank You

Comment: I read, “Electromagnetic waves, whether viewed classically or in terms of quantized photons, are not affected by static electrical or magnetic fields. They have no charge. Nevertheless, they do exert electrical and magnetic forces on charged particles and magnetic particles.
Does the material of the double slit interferes with the photons?

Comment: It looks like the photon(s) are absorbed by the magnetic field then taken to the dipole (invariant mass). It looks like these dipoles are entangled.

Comment: It's unclear what the title of your question has to do with its body, or why you would think the material of the slits is relevant (as long as they block whatever you're shooting through the slits).